# How to specify my IP when creating a Security Group in CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

In CloudFormation I am trying to create a Security Group with an Ingress rule to only allow my IP address access to port 22. However I cannot seem to find any documentation on this or any solutions online.

I do not want to open the Security Group to the internet, and would like to keep it locked down as possible. I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions on how to do this?

```
Resources:
  SecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Example
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 22
          ToPort: 22
          CidrIp: # My IP Address
```

EDIT: I guess it's not possible solution from the answer below is to just do:

```
Parameters:
  IpAddress:
    Description: Your IP Address
    Type: String

Resources:
  SecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Example
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 22
          ToPort: 22
          CidrIp: !Sub '${IpAddress}/24'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your IP address in CIDR notation. You can find your IP from [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=what%20is%20my%20ip) (or other sites). Example:

```
CidrIp: 1.2.3.4/32
```

Ideally you would provide this as a [parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html) to your CloudFormation template so that it wasn't hard-coded in your template. You could even determine it programmatically (prior to creating your stack), for example:

```
$ curl ifconfig.co
```

If your public IP changes over time (e.g. your DHCP reservation expires and your ISP allocates you a new IP address), then perform a CloudFormation stack update, supplying the new IP as an input parameter.

Comment: Sorry, I clarify is it possible to automate this? I don't want to be modifying my CF template every time I want to launch a stack.

Answer (score 5):

AS mentioned before you could do following:
First add required parameter to your CloudFormation template

```
Parameters:
  homeIp: 
    Type: String
    Description: my changing ip
```

then call `update-stack` or `create-stack` with the `curl` command to identify the current IP.

```
aws cloudformation update-stack \
--stack-name test --template-body file://test.yml \
--parameters ParameterKey=homeIp,ParameterValue=$(curl -s http://checkip.amazonaws.com/)/32
```

by doing `curl` to http://checkip.amazonaws.com/ it will respond with current ip. Important to add `/32` at the end as security groups require cidr blocks to be provided.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks.